# Neo4J Nodes vs Relationship Entities

Tags: graph, neo4j, spring-data

I am working the examples of NEO4J found inside Spring Data's book.

```
 Nodes         - Product, Person, Order

 Relationships - (Order) Items (Product), (person) Reviewed (product)
```

I am designing my first Neo4J database and coming to a situation where the Review *might* be better served as a Node instead of a Relationship.

such that a Review could now have a COVERS relationships

```
 Review COVERED Order , Review COVERED Product
```

This review would span multiple COVERED relationships in a sense.

Are there any thoughts on creating a Node Entity vs Node Relationship?  Neo4J seems very flexible... if I change my mind it seems I could modify this later, yes?

It just seemed strange to be repeating essentially the same review text in a relationship, across multiple nodes... and to instead save computational space and create one review node

```
 Review Node Entity
   - String comments
   - int stars
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost thing while designing is to jot down on a white board a rough model which will give an insight to what one is intending to achieve.

In this scenario, if you keep `REVIEW` node separate there will in fact extra nodes and relationships created than reducing the computational space.

```
(PERSON)-[:GIVEN]->(REVIEW)-[:COVERED]->(PRODUCT)
```

So consider asking a question (use-case) Get me reviews of a product A?

The graph first will need to check all `REVIEW` nodes connected to `PRODUCT A` by relationshiptype `COVERED`, then again have to trace back to `PERSON` node to get who gave the review.

But if you do `(PERSON)-[:REVIEWED]->(PRODUCT)`

You would just need to query once all relationshiptypes `REVIEWED` incoming at `PRODUCT A` from `PERSON` node. And the `comments` and `stars` you can store as relationship attribs.

So I think keeping it connected directly via `REVIEWED` with attribs on `REVIEWED` will be neater design and less complex

Comment: So you'd recommend doubling up the review data, into two Relationships?

Comment: Neo4j 2.0 allows to store attributes on relations . So you can save the review data as attributes on REVIEWED relationship

Comment: I'm aware of that fact... but if the review covered TWO nodes.. I need to write TWO relations..  That seemed inefficient, since I am now doubling the amount of data stored.

Comment: i think every product will have its own separate review right.Shouldnt it be ideal to separate the reviews of different products so that if you want to back track a particular product review it would be easier .  
Anyway in case review covered two nodes.. If you create a separate node.. as per match pattern 1 in my answer there will be 2 relation COVERED and 1 REVIEW node and 1 GIVEN relation. 
As per match pattern 2 in my answer there would be just 2 REVIEWED relationships.

Comment: The single review per product doesnt hold for the data i am working with.. Ill try two instances .. One where reviews are nodes with multiple relations... And one where the reviews double up relations